# Building JQGrid with Dropdowns and checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have used jqgrids to display static values. But I have a scenario where I need to have checkboxes and dropdown values to be displayed in JQGrid columns. Depending upon whether I check or uncheck the checkbox. Any thoughts or comments on how to build jqgrids with Dropdowns and Checkboxes?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use the `checkbox` formatter to display a cell as a checkbox. As part of the colmodel:

```
// A checkbox that is read-only until the user edits the row
{name:'my_checkbox',index:'my_checkbox', editable:true, 
 edittype:"checkbox", formatter:'checkbox' }

// A checkbox that may be edited at any time
{name:'my_clickable_checkbox',index:'my_clickable_checkbox', sortable:true, 
 formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: {disabled : false}, editable: true,
 edittype:"checkbox"}
```

As for the dropdown, you can pass a custom format function to the editrow function:

```
jQuery('#mygrid').editRow(id, true, formatEditors);
```

Then, inside this function you would want to create a SELECT (or whatever dropdown you need):

```
function formatEditors(id) {
    // Your drop down code here...
    // EG: jQuery("#"+id+"_myDropDownRow","#mygrid").
}
```

So when you edit the row the data will be displayed in a dropdown.

Comment: I am new to this jquery. Basically I am populating a jqgrid which works fine. But this checkbox should be visible when the grid gets loaded. But I am not able to do that. Can you give me a sample on where your code snippet might fit in. Just the JQ grid cosntruction is enough. I dont see enough tutorials in this area.

Comment: I could not see you examples.