# ASP.net MVC: JQGrid - display checkbox for boolean column

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I want to be able to display a boolean field as a checkbox but I can't find anything on the internet which gives a solution. See below, I've tried to return html which renders a checkbox but the entries are all false and they are editable, which I don't want.

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong please? Why is this so HARD!? (Should I be solving this with CSS?)
Many thanks,
Pete

```
@Html.Grid(new GridControl()
              .SetName("grid")
              .SetListUrl(Url.Action("SearchForRequest", "Requests"))
              .SetPageSize(100)
              .SetIsAutoSize(true)
              .SetHttpVerb(HttpVerbs.Post)
              .SetHeight("300")
              .SetAdditionalAttributes(",datatype:'local'")
              .SetColumns<RequestSummaryViewModel>(cs =>
              {
                  cs.Add(x => x.EvidenceRequired).SetCaption("Evidence Required").SetFormatter("function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {return '<input type=checkbox value=' + cellvalue + '/>'}");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know which control base on jqGrid you use, but I guess that you can use the [predefined](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3apredefined_formatter#predefined_format_types) 'checkbox' formatter with `SetFormatter('checkbox')` instead of the usage of [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_formatter).

Answer (score 0):

I don't use JQGrid but if the Html you output is correct, then simply add the `readonly` attribute to your input and the `checked` attribute if the value is true. 
This, in theory, should solve your problem.

Also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275598/building-jqgrid-with-dropdowns-and-checkboxes/2276056#2276056) should be of help.